# Is there an alternative Google Play Store app?

Tags: android, package-manager, play-store

I'm searching for an alternative Google Play Store app/client.

Don't get me wrong: I don't want an alternative "app market", I want an alternative Play Store client for Android.

That means I want to have the same app collection as in Google Play Store. And all apps come from / load directly from Google Play Store. All apps have to come from Google servers. And the app has to do the same things as the Google Play Store app.

**A similar example would be:** I'm a customer from GMX Mail, but I don't want to install the GMX Mail app client on my phone. So I install another e-mail client app. Now I receive the same GMX emails from the same GMX server with an other e-mail client.

**My problem is:** I want to use my Android phone without a Google account, so I have disabled all my Google services. Now I'm installing all apps via an APK downloader, which is very hard, especially for daily app updates. So is there an app which downloads, installs, uninstalls and updates all my apps/APKs, like the Google Play Store app?

P.S.: The alternative store does not have to work with apps which cost money. I only need it for free apps.

Answer (score 6):

There are several [alternative clients](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets) available. Like [unique_id in his answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18800/185), my first recommendation would be *[AppBrain App Market](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps)*.

But speaking about [Android without Google](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-1), this probably won't work at all: *AppBrain* depends on the *Google Play Store* app when it comes to download the `*.apk` and install the app.

---

As I've pointed out in my article series on this topic (linked above), this is where the **[NOGAPPS project](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1715375)** comes into play. It offers e.g. the *BlankStore* app, which is a "naked" variant of the *Google Playstore App* – stripped down to the essentials: You can search the *Playstore*, you can install free apps and those you already have bought (you cannot, however, use it to *buy* apps – that you'd have to do e.g. via the Web frontent of the store itself), and you can check for updates to apps you have installed (actively; there are no update notifications).

In addition to that, I'd recommend to install **[StripSearch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hasslefixes.stripsearch)** – which offers additional features when searching for apps: you can tell it what permissions the searched app should *not* have, and it limits the result set accordingly:

[image: StripSearch] [image: StripSearch] [image: StripSearch] [image: StripSearch]
<sup>*StripSearch* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hasslefixes.stripsearch); click images for larger variants)</sup>

And not only that, as the screenshots show: you can modify filter presets and create your own, you also can set a price limit, and more.

---

That's the combination I use on my "Google-free devices", and it works perfectly: license validation for payed apps included (via *BlankStore* that is), installing/updating apps, all that. Additionally I'm using *F-Droid*, and download `*.apk` files from the safe "Apps" repository on Aptoide (see [How safe is it to use Aptoide?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/74618/16575) on our sister-site Android.SE). Only thing I miss on those devices is *Google Cloud Messaging* – as without that the *Stack Exchange* app doesn't notify me of events like new answers to my questions, or a comment addressed to me. For accessing the *Google Play Store* without using any of the *GApps*, to my knowledge there is no better combination. Though, as you've already figured, you could also use *AppBrain* as front-end: I've not tested this, but I guess it would then use *BlankStore* for installs/updates – as *BlankStore* poses to be *PlayStore* (all NOGAPPS apps emulate the Google APIs, so this should work).

Comment: Really a usefull one, I've downloaded `BlankStore` app and created play store id using the method mentioned in the _NOGAPPS_ thread in _XDA_ (right now my mobile is not in my hand), So just an Installation and applying the credintials are enough in `BlankStore` or what ?

Comment: @unique_id yes (including the `ANDROID_ID` used by *GServices* – not to confuse with the "normal `ANDROID_ID`). Looks a bit barebone: when started, you see an empty screen and might thing it's not working – but that's why it's called *Blank* Store :) You've got to search for something, or let it show your apps already in use. No introductional ad screens etc. But as it even uses the package name of the Playstore app, it should play well together with *AppBrain*. Have you tried?

Comment: not yet, am at work now btw does it work with Android 5.0.1 ?

Comment: I can't tell – don't have any device running Lollipop yet. But I don't see why it shouldn't.

Comment: ok well am using a device running 5.0.1,I'll try to install and tell you

Comment: Force close on my device

Comment: @unique_id you can check with their Github issues (and report it there if that's not yet done). Btw: Your device has no GApps installed, right? And you've installed *BlankStore* as system app? It cannot co-exist with the regular *Playstore* app as their realms/namespaces conflict.

Comment: Your device has no GApps installed, right?> **Yes**,  And you've installed BlankStore as system app?> **No**

Comment: @unique_id Ah. The "No" is the problem. So you haven't followed the instructions :)

Comment: Installed BlankStore a System App, unfortunately again "FC"

Comment: I rawly remember having had the same issue about a year ago. But I cannot remember how I've solved that back then. You're using the latest version (0.7.2)? I know there was a version bump between "my problem" and "BS working on my device", so it could be that. And you're sure you've [followed the instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=29115263&postcount=84)? Including adjusting the file permissions and setting up the Android_Id?

Comment: What i've done on my Android 5.0.2 is Installed BS(0.7.2) in 'system/priv-app' and changed permission to `-rw-r--r-`, And open BS provide android Id along with username and pwd, when click on installed app or search FC, did I missed something ?

Comment: @unique_id No, that sounds complete. I'd recommend to check the main thread on XDA plus the issues (open and closed ones) on Github. If no solution shows up there, ask in either of the two places. I'm out of ideas with that (except for what `adb logcat` might give clues to). But that's nothing we should discuss here – though naming the solution when found would be a good idea then :)

Comment: GCM can be used by microG (GSMCore) if you install the GsfProxy apk. Here is how to proceed:
- Install Xposed
- Enable signature faking using this Xposed module: https://github.com/thermatk/FakeGApps
- Enable the Xposed module
- Reboot
- Install GmsCore: http://files.brnmod.rocks/apps/GmsCore/Latest/play-services-core-debug.apk
- Install GsfProxy: http://files.brnmod.rocks/apps/GsfProxy/Latest/services-framework-proxy-debug.apk
- Install BlankStore if needed, FakeStore otherwise
- Reboot
- Add a Google account in Settings > Accounts
- Dial *#*#CHECKIN#*#* to checkin.
Then GCM should work.

Comment: Forgot to tell you should enable GCM in microG settings, after you installed it and rebooted, just before you dial CHECKIN.

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq *microG* is the successor of *NOGAPPS*, right, and installation works much smoother and easier. My corresponding article in the "Android without Google" series [can be found here](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-5a). ***I strongly recommend not to use `.apk` files from some weird file hosters:*** the project is hosted at Github, and the `.apk` files are available there. For details, see my linked article and the XDA thread linked from there. BTW: The question was not about *Play Services*, but just *Play Store*.

Comment: Huge kudos for your suggestion again Izzy, I'm definitely going to try this later on. I'm used to downloading an apk on my PC then WIFIing it over to my droids. Sadly so many things rely on the Google Service Framework that I was forced to flash it. I'll probably do a reinstall later on, definitely trying this and ditching apps that require Google Services and stuff

Comment: Good luck, @FONZ! I'm using *microG* for quite a while now, and am satisfied. But keep in mind while it covers a lot, it doesn't cover everything – e.g. apps insisting on performing their `vending.CHECK_LICENCE` at every start won't work. So far, in my case, that affects only one app – and its dev already agreed to do something about ;)

Answer (score 2):

Am using [AppBrain App Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&hl=en) as an alternative for Play Store

because

The best way to find new apps in Google Play (Android market).
Make the Android market usable, and find your next favorite app, live wallpaper or widget:

> - App recommendations
> - New and hot apps of the day
> - Find top Android apps with a price drop
> - Share your best apps (eg twitter/facebook)
> - Tracks market update: notifies of updates available
> - Fast uninstaller
> - Browse "my apps" on www.appbrain.com and install apps with a sync instead of barcode scanner
> - Keep your list of installed apps as a backup on AppBrain.com AppBrain is the best way to discover top Android apps in the Android
>     market and to manage your apps. The recommended apps helper provides
>     recommendations based on what you already use. We also have
>     recommended games. It does not work with the Amazon app store. The
>     manage apps is like a killer file explorer / task manager for your
>     already installed apps:
> - Start app, Quick uninstaller, share to Facebook
> - Fast sync widget to access AppBrain from the desktop and backup your apps to the cloud
> - app2sd functionality to move apps to sd (app 2 sd)
> - Find market update: notifies you of any updates available Discover cool apps and top games in the Android market:
> - sort by hot apps today, hot apps this week, highest rated apps, price drops etc
> - Filter apps by free apps, paid apps, price reduced apps, app2sd enabled apps, new apps
> - Fast search over the entire Android market
> - Unlike applanet or black market, these are only legal apps.

AppBrain is the best app market and app discovery tool for Android apps from the Android Market. It allows you to easily find the best apps in the Market, the free apps and downloads, the price drops, live wallpaper, widgets and much more.

Comment: @User43983 I was just writing my answer while you've posted your comment. Thanks for pointing out search indeed works without GServices – but in fact, *AppBrain* relies on the *Google Play Store* app to install/update apps. Working alternative in [my answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18806/185) :)

Answer (score 0):

Times are changing, and 3 years have passed – so let me add another candidate: **[YalpStore](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/).** Fits all your criteria:

- no need to have a Google account configured on your device
- can access Play Store anonymously for free apps (using a pre-configured account)
- can access it with your credentials (if you provide them) for free and paid apps
- no need for another app to download/install

[image: YalpStore] [image: YalpStore]

You need once to install the app from F-Droid, as well as get its updates there, though. I'm using it on my Google-free devices for a while (as BlankStore stopped working and is no longer maintained), it works reliably.